# What is right way to tmux with fabric django?

Tags: ssh, django, session, fabric, tmux

1.I am doing this on local machine

```
tmux new -s amazon
```

then I ssh in to the server into tmux window

```
shh user@amazon
```

then I detach it ctrl b-d

Into fabfile.py I am doing like this

```
local("tmux a -t amazon") #attaching detached session
local("./myscript") #problem here the tmux session pops on django runserver 
#and waits for input
```

**Problem : Tmux session pop up in Django dev server and doesnt run ./myscript line and waits forever. What I am doing wrong?**

Note: ./myscript  resides on remoteserver

Comment: Besides your current problem: Are you sure you want to open your `tmux` session on your local machine and doing `ssh` from this session? Doesn't make this the idea of "if the connection breaks, the script will continue to run" a bit pointless...? (Not sure if I get you right, if not, I'm sorry.)

Comment: My script is a starting another server listening on some port so its ok even if connection breaks. anyways thanks for your attention I found the solution.  I am posting above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to keep the session detached and run commands via

```
 tmux send-keys -t <session-name> "Command ENTER"
```